# Interplay of values between two vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two vectors `o` and `c` of equal length:

```
o = [-1 -1 -1  0 0 0 1 1 0  0];
c = [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 0 -1];
```

`o` represents opening signals (neg or pos) and `c` represents closing signals, assuming an opening signal has preceeded it with opposite sign. Only one signal can be active at a time so consecuitive signals must be ignored. In the two vectors above, my first signal would be in `o(1)` and its corresponding closing signal would be found in `c(6)`. This also means that the opening signals in `o(2)` and `o(3)` should be ignored and my next opening signal is found at `o(7)` with its corresponding close at `c(10)`, consequently leading to a void signal at `o(8)`

I am trying to find a vectorized solution to identifying a correct sequence or indices of opened/closed signals to produce something along the lines of the following solution example:

```
o = [-1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0];
c = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 -1];
```

I can obviously solve this by looping through each element in a for loop but since my dataset can be up to millions of elements and I find looping in Matlab can be rather 'expensive', I would greatly appreciate if someone has a solution to my problem that is more matrix-oriented, or through `arrayfun` or something equivalent that may make the code more efficient?

Comment: it is not clear what the -1, 0 and 1 in the vectors means.

Comment: @Patrik: Would make more sense if the last element of `c` is `1`. Do you have any control on how the `o` and `c` are created?

Comment: @shahar_m: the values represents signals (-1/1 - zero is no signal). Signals are opened on `o` and closed in `c`.

Comment: @eat: No, the last element i `c` closes a positive signal opened in `o(7)` so the closing signal must be negative. Yes, I do control how `o`and `c` are created. They are generated based on a time series when values are above or below a threshold. The threshold for `c` is lower than `o`

Comment: @Patrik: So can I assume then that the pattern is simple alternating positive/ negative or negative/ positive `1`?

Comment: @eat: Signals in `o` can be either positive or negative (1/-1) and they are closed by a subsequent element in `c` with a counter value (-1/1). There is no specific pattern for when signals will occur in `o`or `c`. I can only have one active open signal, hence the need to remove the "redundant" signals. Don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: @Patrik: Most probably a straightforward solution exists. Just can't figure it from your description. Can you show the code to solve this with loop and/ or some more examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually looping is not more expensive as performing some other operation which just hiddes the loop behind another function (e.g. arrayfun). From your text it just sounds that you just chose the wrong algorithm. Your problem sounds very linear, that is O(n), but you write about loop in loop which means O(n^2). With millions of elements quadratic runtime is not so nice.

The algorithm you want is something like this:

```
open = 0;

for i=1:length(o)
  if (open == 0) 
     open=o(i)
  else 
     o(i) = 0;
  end
  if (c(i) ~= -open) 
     c(i) = 0;
  else 
     open = 0;
  end
end
```

It maybe needs some finetunig, as you didnt describe in detail e.g. what the order of the c and o signals are (e.g. if the same index opens and closes is first the open processed or the closed, my example code assumes open), or whether the order of the signals is always ok, or if there must be some error treatment - but I guess you get the idea of the single loop.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion is along the lines of what I am currently doing but since this piece of code accounts for the majority of my processing time, I was hoping that someone woule have a "magic" formula that would speed things up. :-)

Comment: For the above code matlab needs less than one second on o and c vectors with 2.5 x 10^6 entries. Basicly I see no way of accelerating it and esp I see no need for it - or do you some other calculations (or how many million entries do you have)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff`, along with some logical operations to get your answer.

```
o=[-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
oFinal=abs(diff([0,o])).*o;

oFinal=

    -1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

The trick is that the output of `diff` and your original vector `o` both have a non-zero value at the same index only for the first occurrence of the value in `o` (i.e., first occurrence in a chain). So, by multiplying it element-wise with `o`, you get your answer. The `abs` is to ensure that a sign change doesn't occur due to the output from `diff`.

The approach is similar for `c`, and I'll leave that for you to try :)

Comment: Thanks. I see that your solution does work for the example I gave. Unfortunately, I can have slighty more complex data, e.g if `o=[1,1,0,1,0]` and `c=[1,1,0,1,-1]`. In this case a `diff` of `o` would create `o=[1,0,0,1,0] (using your method with a leading zero) but I would actually want to ignore the signal in `o(4)` since the `o(1)` signal is not closed until `c(5)`. Many thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question earlier, but I get it now. It's a little more involved than simply using `diff` as I had done, but I'm fairly certain it can be done without loops by building on it. I don't have time right now, but I'll update it when I think of something.